# Expectation of iid Bernoulli Function

Tags: statistics, expected-value, variance

For $X_1$, $X_2$,..., $X_n$  iid Bernoulli$(p)$, I am looking to calculate $E\left[\dfrac{1}{n - \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i}\right]$, but am having trouble doing so. I know the sum of iid Bernoulli's is Binomial, but I am not sure how this applies to this expectation, besides the fact that E[$\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$] = np. Any ideas?

Comment: Your first problem is that $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i}{n - \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i}$ is undefined when $X_1 = \dots = X_n = 1$.

Comment: What's with the constant deleting and reposting?

Answer (score 2):

The below shows the steps for $n+1-\sum X_{i}$ in the numerator -
as the comment by Misha Lavrov says $n$ does not work.

**{Step 1 - rewrite the expectation for a general X:}**

Let $X$ be a random variable on $[0,1]$ with $X<1$ (we don't want
to deal with a $0\cdot\infty$ type product in an expectation in full
generality - the underlying integrand's behaviour around the singularity
of the function should be observed more carefully). To calculate the
expectation we can use Taylor expansion (everything's non-negative):

$$
\mathsf{E}\left(\frac{X}{1-X}\right)=\mathsf{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X^{i}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathsf{E}X^{i}
$$

**{Step 2 - Calculate $\mathsf{E}X^{i}$ for the specific case:}**

MGF calculation with Bernulli, we can plug in the following to the
above:

$$
X=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(X_{1}+\ldots+X_{n}\right)
$$

$$
G_{p}(t)=\left(1-p\right)+\exp\left(\frac{t}{n+1}\right)p
$$

Hence we have to calculate the derivatives of the $n$th power of
this - by independence, so use the binomial expansion:

$$
G_{p,n}\left(t\right)=\left(\left(1-p\right)+\exp\left(\frac{t}{n+1}\right)p\right)^{n}=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\left(1-p\right)^{n-j}p^{j}\exp\left(\frac{tj}{n+1}\right)
$$

Which is simple enough for terms of the form $d\exp\left(ct\right)$:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t^{i}}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\left(1-p\right)^{n-j}p^{j}\exp\left(\frac{tj}{n+1}\right)\right)=\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\left(1-p\right)^{n-j}p^{j}\frac{j^{i}}{\left(n+1\right)^{i}}\exp\left(\frac{tj}{n+1}\right)\right)
$$

For the expectation, we need to use $t=0$.

Hence:

$$
\mathsf{E}X^{\ell}=\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\left(1-p\right)^{n-j}p^{j}\frac{j^{\ell}}{\left(n+1\right)^{\ell}}\right)
$$

Plug this in, switch the sums - everything's non-negative:

$$
\sum_{\ell=1}^{\infty}\mathsf{E}X^{\ell}=\sum_{\ell=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\left(1-p\right)^{n-j}p^{j}\frac{j^{\ell}}{\left(n+1\right)^{\ell}}\right)=
$$
Geometric series:
$$
=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\left(1-p\right)^{n-j}p^{j}\sum_{\ell=1}^{\infty}\frac{j^{\ell}}{\left(n+1\right)^{\ell}}=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\frac{\left(1-p\right)^{n-j}p^{j}}{1-\cfrac{j}{n+1}}\cfrac{j}{n+1}=
$$
And finally take what the binomial coefficient is to arrive at:
$$
=\frac{p \left(1-p^n\right)}{1-p}
$$

Comment: Variance calculation should work the same way - Taylor expansion with $x^2(1-x)^{-2}=\sum_{i=2}^{\infty} i x^{i+1}$, re-use the expectations calculated here and then simplify it